# How can I make url in yii2 like this?

Tags: php, yii2

Hi i want to make url like this in yii2
example.com/pagename

example.com/folder1/pagename

example.com/folder1/folder2/pagename

My code

path:- site/pages/folder1/folder2/

Add this in main-local.php

```
'< view >' => 'site/pages',                
'folder1/< view >' => 'site/folder1',
```

'folder2/< view >' => 'site/folder1/folder2',

at sitecontroller i add this first is working but second is not working 404 error

```
'pages' => [    
    'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',       
    'viewPrefix' =>'pages',        
 ],          

'folder1' => [         
    'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',       
    'viewPrefix' =>'pages/folder1',        
 ],    

'folder2' => [             
    'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',           
    'viewPrefix' =>'pages/folder1/folder2',                
 ],
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i was used a method like yours need i hope its help you. but i didn't test folder2. So you can test and send me results,too.:)

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<folder:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<folder>/<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ]
 ]
```